# What are the use of bower and nuget?

Tags: git, installer

I am developing an application with the `MetroUI CSS` framework. I looked their documentation and it contains a [link to github](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS). When I saw the github page then there is mention at the bottom of the page about installing with **bower** and **nuget**. So I want to know :

1) what is the reason of the installation ?

2) where to find `bower` and `nuget` ?

3) Isn't it sufficient to download the zip file and copy directories and files inside my computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower ( http://bower.io/ ) and nuget (https://www.nuget.org/) are both package managers. If you are already using either of these it makes sense to install the MetroUI CSS. It takes care of zipping, copying etc for you and makes it a lot easier to reinstall, uninstall or upgrade afterwards plus it keeps track of all the things you installed.

Comment: so they make the copy of directories and files ?

Comment: More or less. When you typ in "Package-Install Metro.UI.CSS" Nuget will look for the package (online) and perform all the actions required to install it. This usually means downloading files, placing them in the correct location but it will also tell you if the package you are installing has dependencies you're missing and install these as well. See here for an example:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/installing-nuget-packages-directly-from.html